# Validator in Angular 9 Reactive Forms compare passwords

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular9

As shown in the form it appears that it does not show the validator value of the form group nested within another form group.

I am validating this form to change passwords, the required validation works but the comparison of controls does not show anything, I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

```
<form [formGroup]="changePasswordForm">
    <mat-form-field fxFill>
      <mat-label>Contraseña actual</mat-label>
      <input (blur)="logValidationErrors()" matInput name="oldPassword" [type]="oldHide ? 'password':'text'"
        formControlName="oldPassword">
      <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="oldHide =!oldHide" [attr.aria-label]="'hide password'"
        [attr.aria-pressed]="oldHide">
        <mat-icon>{{oldHide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.oldPassword">{{formErrors.oldPassword}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <div formGroupName = "passwordGroup">
      <mat-form-field fxFill>
        <mat-label>Nueva contraseña</mat-label>
        <input (blur)="logValidationErrors()" matInput name="newPassword" [type]="newHide ? 'password':'text'"
          formControlName="newPassword">
        <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="newHide =!newHide" [attr.aria-label]="'hide password'"
          [attr.aria-pressed]="newHide">
          <mat-icon>{{newHide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.newPassword">{{formErrors.newPassword}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field fxFill>
        <mat-label>Confirmar contraseña</mat-label>
        <input (blur)="logValidationErrors()" matInput name="confirmNewPassword"
          [type]="confirmHide ? 'password':'text'"
          formControlName="confirmNewPassword">
        <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="confirmHide =!confirmHide" [attr.aria-label]="'hide password'"
          [attr.aria-pressed]="confirmHide">
          <mat-icon>{{confirmHide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.confirmNewPassword ||formErrors.passwordGroup">{{formErrors.confirmNewPassword ? formErrors.confirmNewPassword : formErrors.passwordGroup}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </form>
```

to componenet.ts

```
  changePasswordForm: FormGroup;

  oldHide = true;
  newHide = true;
  confirmHide = true;

  @Input() set errors(value: string) {
    console.log(value);
  };

  @Output()
  save: EventEmitter<IChangePassword> = new EventEmitter<IChangePassword>(null);

  @Output()
  validate: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>(false);

  validationMessages = {
    oldPassword: {
      required: 'password required',
      minlength: 'error min length '
    },
    newPassword: {
      required: 'new password required',
      minlength: 'error min length'
    },
    confirmNewPassword: {
      required: 'confirm password required',
      minlength: 'erro min length',
      
    },
    passwordGroup: {
      passwordMistmatch: 'error match'
    }
  };

  formErrors = {
    oldPassword: '',
    newPassword: '',
    confirmNewPassword: '',
    passwordGroup:''
  };

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.changePasswordForm = this.fb.group({
      oldPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
      passwordGroup: this.fb.group({
        newPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
        confirmNewPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]]
      },{ validator: matchPassword})
    });

    this.changePasswordForm.statusChanges.subscribe(result => this.validate.emit(result === 'VALID'));
    this.changePasswordForm.valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
      this.logValidationErrors(this.changePasswordForm);
      this.save.emit(result as IChangePassword)
    });

  }

  logValidationErrors(group: FormGroup = this.changePasswordForm): void {

    Object.keys(group.controls).forEach((key: string) => {
      const abstractControl = group.get(key);
      this.formErrors[key] = '';
      if (abstractControl && !abstractControl.valid
        && (abstractControl.touched || abstractControl.dirty)) {
        const messages = this.validationMessages[key];
        for (const errorKey in abstractControl.errors) {
          if (errorKey) {
            this.formErrors[key] += messages[errorKey] + ' ';
          }
        }
      }

      if (abstractControl instanceof FormGroup) {
        this.logValidationErrors(abstractControl);
      }
    });
  }
}

function matchPassword(group: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
  const passwordControl = group.get('newPassword');
  const confirmPasswordControl = group.get('confirmNewPassword');

  if (passwordControl.value === confirmPasswordControl.value || confirmPasswordControl.pristine) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return { 'passwordMistmatch': true };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is in the angular material tool,  we replace with

{{formErrors.confirmNewPassword ? formErrors.confirmNewPassword : formErrors.passwordGroup}}